# phonegap develop in android studio ,config.xml error uri is not registered

Tags: android, xml, cordova

I've new a project,and follow step:

platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/com/squareup  copy_to      app/src/main/java/com
platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org           copy_to      app/src/main/java
platforms/android/assets                       copy_to      app/src/main
platforms/android/res/config.xml               copy_to      app/src/main/res

everything is OK,but in config.xml,the following Uri is burn: Uri is not registered

at last, app run success but tips: error:error initializing Cordova: class not found

Comment: Which version of cordova ?

Comment: Better make use of CLI instead of copy

Comment: because I use Android Studio which build by gradle,but cordova generated the project which build by ant.It runs find if execute `cordova run android`,but I want to know some message logs by emulator .

Answer (score 7):

To remove the Uri is not registered message you can go to

`Android Studio -> Preferences -> Languages & Frameworks -> Schemas & DTDs`

Then add `http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets` to `Ignored Schemas and DTDs`